# How can I let the output be printed backwards?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code with the help of (https://stackoverflow.com/users/271641/marat)

```
def diagsUpRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [['']*i + row + ['']*(n-i-1) for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return [''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)]
```

and the output I get is this

```
['r', 'ax', 'wap', 'byqt', 'izbru', 'tceswn', 'hibxm', 'eovr', 'giw', 'to', 't']
```

Now, I want my code to print the same strings but from bottom to top like

```
[ 'r', 'xa, 'paw', 'tqyb', 'urbzi', 'nwsect', 'mxbih', 'rvoe', 'wig', 'ot', 't']
```

I tried to do that in my function by adding `reversed()` into the function like this

```
def diagsUpRight(M):
    n = len(M)
    m = [['']*i + row + ['']*(n-i-1) for i, row in enumerate(M)]
    return (reversed[''.join(col) for col in zip(*m)])
```

but the output prints `None` when I call it.

What am I doing wrong here, and what is the right code to get my desired output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return [''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*m)]
```